# Hide sender email in sendEmail script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Maybe it's so easy, I'm sorry. But I will be grateful for your help.
I use `sendEmail` script in google spreadsheets. I want that letter recipients not to see my mail in the sender. How can I hide it or replace it on `noreply` in this script?

```
function CustomEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:E");
  var UserData = range.getValues();
  for (i in UserData) {
    var row = UserData[i];
    var name = row[3];
    var email = row[1];
    var score = row[4];
    MailApp.sendEmail(row[1], "text'", "text" + name + "text" + score);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the advanced parameter `noReply` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Be aware that this option is only available to G-Suite users.

If you are not a G-Suite user you can use the advanced parameter `replyTo`

Answer (score 0):

As Casper notes, you can use noReply if you're a G-Suite user.  Also note that solution uses GmailApp instead of MailApp